# i am getting value and name from Input field but getting this error in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```js
const OnBlurHandler = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
  const petnames: string = e.target.name;
  const petvalues = e.target.value;
  const datas = { ...petdata };
  datas[petnames] = petvalues;
  setPetdata(datas);
};
```

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Answer (score 0):

Problem happens because of this line `datas[petnames] = petvalues;`

In your code petnames has assigned as string but you are trying to use it as index of array. You should convert it to number before using it as index of array